# List of errors while starting Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, reboot

Whenever I start Ubuntu 22.04, I get a list of errors then its starts automatically. Here is the few errors I got while staring Ubuntu 22.04. [error list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udybw.jpg)

Please tell me how to resolve all these errors.

Comment: Did you try upgrading your BIOS?

Comment: have you seen this https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=255316 ?

Comment: @Purefan My error list is little different it tells can not resolve symbol.

Comment: @ArturMeinild No I did not try that , my BIOS is up to date. I have dual booting system is the problem lies there???